# ASP.NetCore 2.x scaffolded DB and appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NetCore 2.x, VisualStudio 2019

Hi,

I have tried to read the .NetCore docs on configuration but I am missing something.  I have a project that consumes three databases.  The docs tell me that I have to "scaffold" the DB cpnnections myself now by running something like:

```
    Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=my-db.company.edu;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" -Context MyThingsContext -Schemas "dbo" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models\MyThings
```

This works.  I get the DB context and associated model files.  I also get the `MyThingsContext.cs` file that contains:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=my-db.company.edu;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
```

Note: the `#warning...` line above.  I am actually doing this DB scaffolding three times, once for three different DBs.  Two of the `...Context.cs` files have the `#warning...` line but one has the same comment but in `//warning...` form.

During the build phase I get the two `#warning...`s in the code comment above but not the `//warning`.

Are the `#` and `//` warning versions normal?  This is generated code so I shouldn't mess with it.

Next, since it is warning me to move the connection strings out of code can I just remove the `OnConfiguring` methods after I put the connection strings in `appsettings.json`?

Is there a different/better way to do the DB scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better practice to use configuration files for your specific environment.  `appsettings.Development.json`, `appsettings.Production.json` etc.

So for example:

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyThingsDatabase": "Server=development-db.company.edu;Initial Catalog=DevelopmentDB;Integrated Security=True"
  },
}
```

**appsettings.Production.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyThingsDatabase": "Server=production-db.company.edu;Initial Catalog=ProductionDB;Integrated Security=True"
  },
}
```

Then in your Startup.cs ConfgureServices method:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyThingsContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyThingsDatabase"));
```

There are a myriad of ways you can specify then which environment you're working from. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Shouldn't be `appsettings.Development.json`, `appsettings.Production.json`(in general `appsettings.<ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT>.json)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Fixed now.  I think I recall them using hyphens at one point early on and it's never quite gotten out of my head.  :)

Comment: Thank you all... one of the questions though was about the scaffolded models. since the connection strings are generated in that code by the scaffold system should I remove that code and is there a way to scaffold that leves the connection strings out?

Comment: @7Reeds the scaffolding won't do the configuration files or startup.cs code for you.  You have to move it manually then remove the onconfiguring method.  You do have to pass the connection string to the scaffolding CLI command so that it can connect to the database and see your schema in order to generate your models and context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having ConnectionString used directly in the OnConfiguring method is not only inflexibility of the design, but a potential security breach if you use username/password combination.
You should be using appsettings.json for any connection string and pass appropriate one to the configuration of that dbContext.